# jQuery - bxSlider plugin reloadSlider issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using jQuery with the bxSlider plugin, here is the link to it just incase: http://bxslider.com/

I'm trying to reload the slider and my custom pager after I've removed certain slides from it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(function() {
    var slider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
    });

    $('.list').on('click', '.delete', function() {
        image = $(this).closest('li').find('[type="hidden"]');

        // image.attr('id') contains a string: image-0, image-1, image-2, etc.
        $('#slider, #bx-pager').find('.' + image.attr('id')).remove(); 

        slider.reloadSlider({
            pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
        }); // I have also tried: slider.reloadSlider();
    });
});
```

It works partially. What happens is the slider gets reloaded just fine but it removes the pager completely when it runs the reload.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as I see, this is a bug in bxSlider, in fact, when you call the `reloadSlider` method, internally are called the methods `destroySlider` and `init`.

In the `destroySlider` method the `pagerEl` element is destroyed, this is right if you are not using a custom one, because it is recreated programmatically in the `init` method, but if you are using a custom one it can't be recreated programmatically.

I ended up modifying the `destroySlider` method to check if a custom pager is used, in this case  it must not be deleted.

Here is the before (line 1294):

```
if(slider.pagerEl) slider.pagerEl.remove();
```

And after:

```
if (slider.settings.pagerCustom === '') {
    if(slider.pagerEl) slider.pagerEl.remove();
}
```

I'll post the bug on GitHub as soon as I have the time.

Comment: You're a champ! Thank you a thousandfold =)

Comment: Glad it was helpful :) I just filed a pull request to the project's git.

Comment: @MicheleGargiulo do you have a link to your GitHub Issue / PR ? thanks!

Comment: @DavidBarratt it has been committed from another contribution, here is the link: https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/pull/477